# WebBluetooth Error in Windows 10: "Turn on Bluetooth to allow pairing"

Tags: windows, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, web-bluetooth

My WebBluetooth app works in Chrome Version 77.0.3865.90 on another system, so this is not a Chrome problem, this is a Windows setting problem.  As soon as my web app tries to pair I am getting the message, "Turn on Bluetooth to allow pairing".

Bluetooth is turned on in Windows 10 and I can manually pair my workstation to my Android phone.  I have fiddled with every Windows Bluetooth setting for hours now (disabling devices, etc.).

This is the message:  [image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thx!

Comment: You've given several indications that you believe this is an operational issue (your attempts include changing settings and disabling devices, and you aren't showing your code).  Posts on StackOverflow have to be related to coding issues in some way, operational issues belong elsewhere (SuperUser or possibly webapps stackexchange).

Comment: At this time I am not sure if it is a coding issue or a configuration issue.  I am hoping that someone else has had the same problem and discovered a way to solve it.

Comment: In searching the Chromium code, here is the reference:

chromium
src/chrome/app/generated_resources.grd
Show 9 matches

9357: <message name="IDS_BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_CHOOSER_TURN_ADAPTER_OFF" desc="Text of a link the user can click to get help information when Bluetooth adapter is turned off."> 9358: <ph name="TURN_ON_BLUETOOTH_LINK">$1<ex>Turn on Bluetooth</ex></ph> to allow pairing 9359: </message> 9360: <message name="IDS_BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_CHOOSER_TURN_ON_BLUETOOTH_LINK_TEXT" desc="Text of the 'Turn on Bluetooth' 
<br>
MY ADAPTER IS TURNED ON!!! Why would chrome think it is turned off???

Comment: Perhaps Chrome has not been given permission to use the Bluetooth device.  I did notice that Windows permission settings did start affecting desktop apps at some point (although not so specifically as store apps).  Also, Chrome may have settings to control web-bluetooth (either disabling it completely or restricting it to certain domains)  Finally, the Bluetooth support in Chrome might work with some Bluetooth drivers and not others.  Is Bluetooth working in other webapps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably a Chrome bug. Since I experienced the same problem, I have opened https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1006688 for it.

Comment: Awesome Eckhart!  This is partially a Chrome bug.  The answer is to turn the Windows "Radio Devices" setting to on while Chrome is NOT running.  I think the problem started with a Windows update where this setting was turned off.  https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1006688